# Unreal HandheldAR template: Couldn't find file for package /Script/AugmentedReality requested by async loading code

Tags: ios, arkit, unreal-engine4

I've created an unmodified project using the HandheldAR template, and deployed it to an iPad after building via a remote Mac build server (while it's a Blueprint-only project, a Mac is still required to build AR application).

Project builds and deploys to the device without errors, and certificates report that they're valid, but when I attempt to launch it on the iPad, the default project splashscreen appears, and then the device dumps back to the home screen. Application still appears as a running app, but if I attempt to switch back to it, it just bounces back to the home screen.

Other Blueprint-only UE4 projects deployed from the same machine work as expected on the device.

From the log below, it appears that /Script/AugmentedReality failed to load.

> [2018.08.03-17.56.36:622][  0]LogAIModule: Creating AISystem for world
>   HandheldARBlankMap [2018.08.03-17.56.36:625][  0]LogStreaming: Error:
>   Couldn't find file for package /Script/AugmentedReality requested by
>   async loading code. NameToLoad: /Script/AugmentedReality
>   [2018.08.03-17.56.36:625][  0]LogStreaming: Error: Found 1 dependent
>   packages... [2018.08.03-17.56.36:625][  0]LogStreaming: Error:
>   /Game/HandheldARBP/Blueprints/GameFramework/BP_ARPawn
>   [2018.08.03-17.56.36:628][  0]LogStreaming: Error:
>   ****DumpDependencies [Dependencies]: [2018.08.03-17.56.36:628][  0]LogStreaming: Error:     Export 1
>   /Game/HandheldARBP/D_ARSessionConfig.D_ARSessionConfig
>   [2018.08.03-17.56.36:628][  0]LogStreaming: Error:     Linker is
>   ../../../HandheldAR/Content/HandheldARBP/D_ARSessionConfig.uasset
>   [2018.08.03-17.56.36:628][  0]LogStreaming: Error:         Dep
>   S_BEFORE_C Import     1   /Script/AugmentedReality.ARSessionConfig
>   [2018.08.03-17.56.36:628][  0]LogStreaming: Error:         Dep
>   S_BEFORE_C Import     0
>   /Script/AugmentedReality.Default__ARSessionConfig
>   [2018.08.03-17.56.36:628][  0]LogStreaming: Error: Missing Dependency,
>   request for /Script/AugmentedReality.ARSessionConfig but it hasn't
>   been created yet. [2018.08.03-17.56.36:628][  0]LogStreaming: Error:
>   Could not find class ARSessionConfig to create D_ARSessionConfig
>   [2018.08.03-17.56.36:633][  0]LogProperty: Error: Struct type unknown
>   for property 'StructProperty
>   /Game/HandheldARBP/Blueprints/UI/BP_DebugMenu.BP_DebugMenu_C:UpdateDebugMenuInfo.CallFunc_GetARSessionStatus_ReturnValue';
>   perhaps the USTRUCT() was renamed or deleted?
>   [2018.08.03-17.56.36:633][  0]LogProperty: Error: Struct type unknown
>   for property 'StructProperty
>   /Game/HandheldARBP/Blueprints/UI/BP_DebugMenu.BP_DebugMenu_C:ToggleARMode.CallFunc_GetARSessionStatus_ReturnValue';
>   perhaps the USTRUCT() was renamed or deleted?
>   [2018.08.03-17.56.36:633][  0]LogProperty: Error: Struct type unknown
>   for property 'StructProperty
>   /Game/HandheldARBP/Blueprints/UI/BP_DebugMenu.BP_DebugMenu_C:InitializeDebugButtonStates.CallFunc_GetARSessionStatus_ReturnValue';
>   perhaps the USTRUCT() was renamed or deleted?
>   [2018.08.03-17.56.36:634][  0]LogProperty: Error: Struct type unknown
>   for property 'StructProperty
>   /Game/HandheldARBP/Blueprints/GameFramework/BP_ARPawn.BP_ARPawn_C:ExecuteUbergraph_BP_ARPawn.CallFunc_LineTraceTrackedObjects_ReturnValue.CallFunc_LineTraceTrackedObjects_ReturnValue';
>   perhaps the USTRUCT() was renamed or deleted?
>   [2018.08.03-17.56.36:639][  0]LogLoad: Game class is 'BP_ARGameMode_C'
>   [2018.08.03-17.56.36:640][  0]LogWorld: Bringing World
>   /Game/HandheldARBP/Maps/HandheldARBlankMap.HandheldARBlankMap up for
>   play (max tick rate 0) at 2018.08.03-10.56.36
>   [2018.08.03-17.56.36:640][  0]LogWorld: Bringing up level for play
>   took: 0.000401 [2018.08.03-17.56.36:640][  0]LogGameMode:
>   FindPlayerStart: PATHS NOT DEFINED or NO PLAYERSTART with positive
>   rating [2018.08.03-17.56.36:642][  0]LogUMG: Display: Widget Class
>   BP_MainMenu_C - Loaded Fast Template. [2018.08.03-17.56.36:643][ 
>   0]LogUMG: Display: Widget Class BP_DebugMenu_C - Loaded Fast Template.
>   [2018.08.03-17.56.36:644][  0]LogScript: Warning: Accessed None
>     BP_DebugMenu_C
>   /Engine/Transient.GameEngine_0:GameInstance_0.BP_DebugMenu_C_0
>     Function
>   /Game/HandheldARBP/Blueprints/UI/BP_DebugMenu.BP_DebugMenu_C:InitializeDebugButtonStates:001C
>   [2018.08.03-17.56.36:644][  0]LogScript: Warning: Script call stack:
>     Function
>   /Game/HandheldARBP/Blueprints/UI/BP_DebugMenu.BP_DebugMenu_C:Construct
>     Function
>   /Game/HandheldARBP/Blueprints/UI/BP_DebugMenu.BP_DebugMenu_C:ExecuteUbergraph_BP_DebugMenu
>     Function
>   /Game/HandheldARBP/Blueprints/UI/BP_DebugMenu.BP_DebugMenu_C:InitializeDebugButtonStates
>
> [2018.08.03-17.56.36:644][  0]LogOutputDevice: Warning:
>
> Script Stack: BP_DebugMenu_C.InitializeDebugButtonStates
>   BP_DebugMenu_C.ExecuteUbergraph_BP_DebugMenu BP_DebugMenu_C.Construct
>   BP_ARPawn_C.ExecuteUbergraph_BP_ARPawn BP_ARPawn_C.ReceiveBeginPlay

iPad specs:

- Capacity: 64 GB, Available: 51.35 GB
- Version: 11.4.1 (15G77)
- Model: MQDT2LL/A (Apple 10.5" iPad Pro (64GB, Wi-Fi, Space Gray))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the answer was simply that the Apple ARKit plugin was not enabled. Enabling it and rebuilding corrected the issue.